# Another Jmeter Report On Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins

Actually I am create CI using jmeter (.jmx file) into Jenkins. for reporting I using **Performance Plugin** (follow this [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin)). Is there anything report plugin for jmeter in Jenkins instead of **Performance Plugin**? actually I want to have API report on Jenkins. **Performance Plugin** seems not good enough for API test reporting. it does not show the response message, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Performance plugin is not very suitable for functional testing, its main functions are:

- building performance trend graphs for regression purposes
- conditionally fail the build if metrics start getting worse

Jenkins is **very** flexible and performance plugin is only one of post-build actions, you can publish anything to the build artifacts, for instance you can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) after test execution or use XSL Transformation of the .jtl result file to get single page HTML report using XSL stylesheets from "extras" folder, i.e. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/extras/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl

See [Running a JMeter Test via Jenkins Pipeline - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-test-jenkins-pipeline-tutorial) for example configuration

Comment: **use XSL Transformation of the .jtl result file to get single page HTML report using XSL stylesheets from "extras" folder** can you show me an example on this? want to know how to handle it. @Dmitri T